# MVC Razor Form Set Checkbox to Checked + Lock

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm building a form and have used the default scaffolding option based on my model in visual studio. What I need is for the checkbox to be checked by default when the view is loaded and disabled. I.E I want to preventing the user from changing the checkbox state.

The view code looks like this:

```
@model Models.Checkertest
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Test</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "AccountManagement", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>User Creation</h4>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Enable Bypass", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.box1)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.box1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your action method in your controller, set the `box1` property to true on your model. It would look something like this:

```
var model = new Checkertest {box1 = true};
return View(model);
```

To make the checkbox readonly, set the `readonly` attribute on it, like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.box1, new {@readonly = "readonly"})
```

Comment: The enable checkbox worked perfectly, but the readonly section in the view did not It looks as though it's placing the read only tag in the label.